# Как сделать отдельную страницу в админке WordPress-плагина без использования add_submenu_page?

Tags: php, wordpress, плагин, hook

Итак, имеется меню в админке WordPress для плагина:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
add_menu_page('MyPlugin', 'MyPlugin', 'manage_categories', 'myplugin.php?page=index', array($this, 'index'));
add_submenu_page('myplugin.php?page=index', 'Items', 'Items', 'manage_categories', 'myplugin.php?page=items', array($this, 'items'));
```

На странице: **myplugin.php?page=items** у меня есть кнопка **Add Item**,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

по нажатию которой пользователь переходит на например: **myplugin.php?page=itemAdd** для создания нового Item'а, если действовать по стандарту, то мне надо сделать так:

```
add_submenu_page('myplugin.php?page=index', 'Add Item', 'Add Item', 'manage_categories', 'myplugin.php?page=itemAdd ', array($this, 'itemAdd'));
```

но если я не хочу чтобы у меня страница: **Add Item** имела пункт в меню админки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если мне надо чтобы при переходе по кнопке: **Add Item**, выделенным слева оставался пункт **Items** - **как быть?**

Comment: Вы напишите, что надо сделать по кнопке. Добавить некую информацию в базу?

Comment: По кнопке юзер переходит на форму, заполняет её, ну и если пройдет валидацию полей формы - попадает снова на страницу Items

Comment: У меня будет много подстраниц для страниц админки имеющих ссылку в меню слева, однако создавать ссылки в меню слева для всех этих подстраниц - безумие!

Comment: Да сделайте свой интерфейс ввода на странице плагина и все. Поля, кнопки - все вместе.

Comment: Это как это, не совсем понял?

Comment: Ранее, я когда-то делал так, при нажатии на кнопку Add Item, пользователь уходил по адресу: myplugin.php?page=items&action=add, ну и в коде я ставил проверку на action - и соответственно подставлял нужный интерфейс или функционал. Но сейчас такой финт не проходит - WP пишет что у меня нет прав доступа к странице по адресу: myplugin.php?page=items&action=add, добавочный &action=add ему не нравится!

Comment: Ну вот так, например: http://take.ms/tG8j4  Форма тут самая примитивная, но принцип понятен, надеюсь.

Comment: Вы похоже меня не поняли ) Зачем мне Ваша форма, я их умею делать. Вопрос как реализовать интерфейс по адресу, без добавления этого адреса в виде пункта в меню плагина слева ? )

Comment: Возможно, не понял. Но если хотите, чтобы интерфейс был в админке, да еще чтобы тот же пункт был выделен - то, скорее всего, - никак.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56294/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-enshtein).

Answer (score 0):

Решение проблемы на моём примере, кнопка и её адрес:

```
<h1>Items <a href="?page=myplugin.php%3Fpage%3Ditems&action=AddItem" class="page-title-action">Add Item</a></h1>
```

в методе items можно написать примерно так:

```
public function items()
{
    if (!empty($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action']!='-1') {
        if (method_exists($this, $_REQUEST['action']))
            return call_user_func(array($this, $_REQUEST['action']));
    }
    // далее функционал или интерфейс если action не передан!
}
```